# accessing static constants with Grails remote control

Tags: grails, groovy

If I have something like this, using the Grails remote control within a test

```
class FooTest {
   static final String CONSTANT = "some constant"
   def remote = new Remote()

   def testUsingRemote() { 
     remote { 
       new DomainObject(name: FooTest.CONSTANT).save()
     }
   }
}
```

the closure may break with NoClassDefFoundError when executed on the remote side because the FooTest class itself isn't in the deployed app.

I can fix it by assigning the constant to a local variable and then using the local variable in the closure (local var available through lexical scope):

```
 def constant = FooTest.CONSTANT
 remote {
   new DomainObject(name: constant).save()
 }
```

What's a good way to fix this across the board?

Ideally: is there any way to resolve or inline constants before serializing the closure?